# How to make a Post request from one website to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Lets say I have two websites, Website-A and Website-B.

Website-A receives a post request (From a third party website), I want to relay this request along with its data to website-B. I tried the below approach but it doesn't seems to navigate to  the website B.

```
string newUrl = "http://localhost/WebSite-B/Test.aspx";

HttpRequest original = HttpContext.Current.Request;

HttpWebRequest newRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newUrl);

newRequest.ContentType = original.ContentType;
newRequest.Method = original.HttpMethod;
newRequest.UserAgent = original.UserAgent;

byte[] originalStream;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    original.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    originalStream = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

Stream reqStream = newRequest.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(originalStream, 0, originalStream.Length);
reqStream.Close();

newRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

newRequest.GetResponse();
```

The GetResponse() doesn't seem to open up or navigate to the requested page.

Please help me to pass on the POST request received by Website-A to Website-B.

Comment: Try giving newRequest.Method = "POST"

Comment: btw hacking is not nice... http://forums.asp.net/t/1919267.aspx

Comment: @Viji, I tried that but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question in another web [site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1920219.aspx?Post%20action%20from%20controller). For your convinience here is a sample code:

```
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string postData = "now=" + strId;
    postData += ("&random=" + random);
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http://www.domain.com/controler/action);
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    newStream.Close();
```

An alternative method to acomplish the same functionality can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: I am missing something here, You create a HttpWebRequest and write that to a stream. when I place this in a Webform Page Load event it doesn't fire any Request. Will this work on webforms ?

Comment: This code simply simulates a web post request so it will work in web forms as well. The thing that would concern me will be why doesnot any request fire? How do you check is the request is generated?

Comment: Shashank, I look at fiddler to see any request is generated and other expectation is the browser will navigate to the URL specified in the request

Comment: I have added another link to the post, I believe this what you are exactly looking for.